# AWS + Django cronjob

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, cron

I used Elastic Beanstalk to get my Django app running on AWS. I want to run a cronjob to update some of my models. I made a custom management command (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/howto/custom-management-commands/) and can run it locally, but if I ssh into my instance and run crontab, I get the error:

> No module named django.core.management

What's the best way to run cronjobs for a Django project on AWS?

Comment: Did you setup a virtualenv on the server? If so, did you make sure to run the manage.py command with the correct python from the virtualenv?

Comment: I didn't setup a virtualenv. Should I? Also, how do I make the manage.py command run with that virtualenv?

Comment: Yes, you should. Basically what'd you end up doing is ```/path/to/virtualenv/bin/python /path/to/manage.py command```. The reason you currently can't run commands is that you haven't installed Django on your server yet.

Comment: I get this error when trying to do anything with manage.py: KeyError: 'RDS_DB_NAME'. That's in my settings file.

Comment: That's due to your environment not being setup on your server. This might be helpful, but you're starting to get into a new question. http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.managing.saving.html

Comment: I've sent their team multiple emails with request for a supported feature, as well as suggestions on implementations. I received an acknowledgement from them, but haven't seen results yet. Dying to have this.

Answer (score 0):

Got this to work (this is undocumented, so it's subject to change at any time)

```
*/10 * * * * source /opt/python/current/env && django-admin.py do_your_thang
```

`/opt/python/current/env` seems to contain not just your "virtual environment" stuff, but the actual variables needed for connecting to the database etc.

I still haven't got any responses on EB + cron + django from EB team.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in **Django 1.10.6** + **AWS ElasticBeanstalk** + **Cronjob**

`* * * * * source /opt/python/run/venv/bin/activate && cd /opt/python/current/app/ && python manage.py do_your_thing > $HOME/cron-sqs.log 2>&1`

**do_your_thing** is a [management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-management-commands/)